# Angular polyfills core-js not working as expected on IE11

Tags: angular, polyfills

I have issues rendering my Angular app in IE 11

I've followed the information here: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

I've also imported the following polyfills:

```
 import 'core-js/es/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es/object';
 import 'core-js/es/function';
 import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es/number';
 import 'core-js/es/math';
 import 'core-js/es/string';
 import 'core-js/es/date';
 import 'core-js/es/array';
 import 'core-js/es/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es/map';
 import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es/set';
 import 'core-js/es/promise';
```

But I'm still getting this two errors in IE:

`SCRIPT5009: 'Symbol' is undefined`

`SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined`

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please share your Angular version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your polyfills should go before any imports in `polyfills.ts` file:

```
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/promise';
/**
 * IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements
 */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```